# EBean mapping Booleans defaulting to false instead of null

Tags: mysql, scala, jpa, playframework, ebean

I've been using Scala + EBean and I have a problem;
I have a model that looks a bit like this;

```
case class SomeModel(name: String) extends Model { 
    var someBool: Boolean = _ 
}
```

The problem is that even though the default value of `someBool` is `null` in the schema, `EBean` fills it up with `0` (it maps it to a `TINYINT` in `mySQL`), I should be able to save a `null` in the fields as well.

(ideally I'd like to keep track of whether or not the field has been set to a value in the model), wherein a `null` for a field would mean the field hasn't been filled in yet.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: You would have the same issues in Java with boolean (primitive, non nullable) versus java.lang.Boolean (nullable) so I guess changing for the corresponding nullable Scala type would fix it: The Scala docs fro Boolean note that it is 'equivalent to Java's boolean primitive type'

Comment: @AlanHay for now, `java.lang.Boolean` works rather perfectly at solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to this is to simply replace `Boolean` with `java.lang.Boolean`, so;

```
case class SomeModel(name: String) extends Model { 
    var someBool: java.lang.Boolean = _ 
}
```